# Laravel how to return virtual generated column on model create

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I have the following table:

```
| id | number_one | number_two | number |
| 1  | 10         | 20         | 10020  |
```

Where `number` is a virtual created combination of `number_one` and `number_two`. Now when accessing a row the Laravel model also does return the `number` as expected.

```
Number::find(1); // returns [ id => 1, number_one => 10, number_two => 20, number => 10020]
```

However when using

```
Number::create(['number_one' => 10, 'number_two' => 21]);
```

It only returns

```
[number_one => 10, number_two => 21, id => 2]
```

So my question is how can I make it return the following on create:

```
[ number_one => 10, number_two => 21, number => 10021, id => 2]
```

And yes I could use a additional query or a `getNumberAttribute` method but would like to avoid this

Comment: well an `insert` statement isn't a `select` so you will probably want to `refresh` the model so it will do a `select` and get all the fields

Comment: on creating model event you can modify number column: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#events-using-closures

Comment: @lagbox this, for now, seems to be the best solution as `fresh` can be chained to `create`

Comment: yea `refresh` returns the current instance with updated attributes and relationships and `fresh` returns a new instance so either way you are getting a model returned from those methods :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `create` is causing an INSERT statement, there isn't a SELECT happening to get the fields from the table. You will notice that if you have a table that has default values and you don't pass those fields you also won't have them in your model.

To get these fields you would need to do a SELECT. You can call `refresh` on the Model instance to have its attributes and relationships refreshed from the database or you can also call `fresh` to get a new instance from the database (basically a `find`). [both methods will return a Model instance]

```
$model = Model::create([...])->refresh();
// or
$model = Model::create([...])->fresh();
```

Comment: Another approach is to manually set the eloquent model's attribute after the insertion.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to set the `number` attribute inside the `created` Eloquent event.

For example, if your table is created like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `numbers` (
    `id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `number_one` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    `number_two` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    `number` BIGINT(20) AS (1000 * number_one + number_two) VIRTUAL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

The virtual column is generated with the SQL expression `(1000 * number_one + number_two)`.

You can do this in your `created` event.

```php
class Number extends Model
{
    protected static function booted()
    {
        self::created(function (self $model) {
            $model->number = DB::scalar('SELECT 1000 * ? + ?', [$model->number_one, $model->number_two]);
        });
    }
}
```

I've used a really basic example, but you could be using very complex sql to generate the number column and this answer would still work. It's not depending on finding the right way to translate SQL to PHP. You just need to be mindful of the bindings.

Granted, it's a bit more boilerplate than using `fresh()` or `refresh()`, but it should achieve the same thing, without having to rehydrate an entire model.